# How do I recover a BTRFS partition formatted by mkfs.btrfs?

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, data-recovery

I've accidentally formatted one of my partitions with btrfs 0.19 filesystem, on 11.04, kernel 2.6.38-8-generic.

The command issued was:

```
mkfs.btrfs -L EADS-old /dev/sdd2.
```

After this I didn't write anything on this disk, it was only mounted few times. And the disk is obviously clean at a first glance.

How do I recover the data from it? It has quite a lot valuable data and I don't afford to backup the whole 1T of data.

I've tried testdisk program but I was unable to find any partitions nor usable data.

Comment: Not confident enough for giving an answer to this as I've never used BTRFS and don't know how widely supported. But have you tried RIP Linux? Mayhaps it has more up to date support for newer filesystems than Ubuntu. http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/

Comment: Thank you, I've googled for hours, but nothing easy and valuable is found. I'll try this also. Testdisk is not working (found just some junks), after all the partitions are unchanged. Photorec did extract housands of files, but this is huge mess and mostly unusable :(

Comment: If you don't backup your data, sooner or later you WILL loose it.  I'm afraid you're just going to have to chalk this up as lesson learned.

Comment: No, I don't used this disks since this time, hoping some day I'll recover them. They were mounted several times in RO mode and some analysis was done by restoring software, but no luck. I extracted 600GB of files in thousands of dirs, with numerical names, and that's all. Maybe I should try again nowadays, when btrfs tools matured?

Comment: Any news on this? I'm really curious how easy it is to recover a formatted btrfs filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) but seen the date of your question you probably removed more/all data in the mean while. PhotoRec does not explicity support BTRFS, but it works filesystem agnostic.